# Create Query for Items Created Last Week [TFS]

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I'm trying to create a query that will show anything with a create date from last week.. [last Monday - Friday] all I've been able to figure out is to use @today-7 but that gives the last 7 days and not technically 'Last Week'

Comment: Can't be done. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the @Today -7 only find those work items created in the past 7 days. There's no query variables like "last week" to get work items from last Monday to last Friday. Instead of using @Today -7, you could enter a specific date time to find work items of last week.
[image]

Here is a user voice about add a query variable to find work items of last week. You could vote: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18426199-add-last-week-month-year-query-variable